# Is there a way to get the raw url of a file in AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

In github, you can click the Raw button and you can get the file's url. Does CodeCommit have that feature?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately and unbelievably, I think the answer is still, **NO**. The Web UI (AWS Console Code-commit) allows you to navigate to any file, view it, and even edit it, but it doesn't allow you to view the raw (and ultimately) **download** it.  So frustrating. This would be a simple feature for them to add via their GetFile API.

Answer (score 2):

CodeCommit repos are protected by IAM credentials, so you're not going to get a direct public URL to the file.

However, if you want to **download the content** of a specific file, you can use the AWS SDK or CLI. Here's an example using the CLI:

```sh
aws codecommit get-file \
  --repository-name my-project \
  --file-path path/to/file.json \
  --query fileContent \
  --output text \
  | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the raw contents of blobs in a CodeCommit repository using the GetBlob API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetBlob.html). Your request needs to be authenticated using appropriate AWS credentials (access key, secret key).

There is currently no way to provide a permanent, public URL for the blob.

Comment: How do you get the blobId?